# How to set alignment in Fire Monkey multi device application at runtime C++ Builder?

Tags: alignment, runtime, firemonkey, c++builder

The main problem is FMX dose not support the `SomeController->Align = alClient;` but that code will work in the VLC application, so after many googling, I find `TAlignLayout.Client` for my case and the documentation of it is [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Align) and [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout), I try many way to use it but it wont work!

I want create Frame in the runtime as you can see in the following code:

```
TSettings *appSettingsFrame;
appSettingsFrame = new TSettings(viewSettings);
appSettingsFrame->Parent = viewSettings;
appSettingsFrame->Align = TAlignLayout.Client;
```

`TSettings` is Fire Monkey Frame and I use the above code in `FormCreate` event to create it, at runtime.

`viewSettings` is `TMultiView` and it's place for `appSettingsFrame`.

If I run application for Android target, the error massage point me to `'TAlinLayout' dose not refer to a value`.

And if I run application for 32-bit Windows target, the error massage point me to `Improper use of typedef 'TAlignLayout'`.

Comment: `TAlignLayout.Client` is Delphi syntax for accessing a scoped enum value.  In C++, it would be `TAlignLayout::Client` instead, or  `Fmx::Types::TAlignLayout::Client` if you need to use the fully qualified name.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, I think your comment is correct answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help someone, I did used `::` instead of `.` to fix issue.

```
TSettings *appSettingsFrame;
appSettingsFrame = new TSettings(viewSettings);
appSettingsFrame->Parent = viewSettings;
appSettingsFrame->Align = TAlignLayout::Client;
```